# SEO ASP.NET 4.0 Forms - set default value in URL

Tags: forms, seo, asp.net-4.0

I am using asp.net 4.0 SEO, and I am trying to figure out if I can have the default value in the URL when it is not specified.

This is my situation: in my global.asax I have added the following route: Races/{Season} - where Season defaults to the current year. So you can type websitenamehere/Races and it would go for the current year. But is it possible to have the default year show up in the URL even when it is not specified? In other words, when I type websitenamehere/Races and click enter, the page loads and then it would show websitenamehere/Races/2010 in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Do a redirect on your page. Check that the url ends in a year, if not then call Response.Redirect with the desired url.